# Django - Annotate count of related objects

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

Let's assume the next models:

```
class A:
   b=models.ForeignKey("B")

class B:
   pass
```

I want to annotate queryset of B count of related A objects

```
def annotate_count_a(b_queryset):
      /* ..... */
```

How to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You annotate with [**`Count`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#id9):

```
from django.db.models import Count


def annotate_count_a(b_queryset):
    return b_queryset.annotate(na=Count('a'))
```

The `B` objects that arise from this queryset will then have an extra attribute `.na` that contains the number of related `A` records.

Comment: Thank you. So does it mean that, Count('a') will access and count objects which is in a reverse relationship with B ?

Comment: @JeremyBearimy: yes, it will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the table of the `A` model and then use `COUNT(a.id)` and `GROUP BY b.id`.